# Unity Instantiated object only moves up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, instance, monodevelop

I have a Light_Spell script attached to a magic wand which is parented to a Razer Hydra hand object. The Light_Spell takes a prefab of a Light which is projected out of it when a button is pressed.
However the light is just moving up, no matter what way I rotate the hand object, it always goes up. I had it working but I changed some code around and can't remember how I got it working in the first place.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    //What happens when bumper is pressed
    if (isSelectedSpell && SixenseInput.Controllers [0].GetButtonDown (SixenseButtons.BUMPER) && triggerIsPressed == false) {
        Rigidbody instantiateProjectile = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation) as Rigidbody;
        instantiateProjectile.position += Vector3.down * 20.0F;
    }
```

I have tried setting Vector3 to up and forward and a whole set of different things. Any ideas on what I should do to make it match the rotation of where the hand is pointing and stuff?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using:

```
instantiateProjectile.position += -instantiateProjectile.transform.up * 20.0f;
```

**Explanation**:

`Vector3.down` is not relative to the transform's rotation, it is a 'down' in World space, that is to say it will always be going down according to the cardinal axes.

`transform.up` is relative to that transform's rotation. If the projectile is rotated, the axes used to obtain "up" are rotated too. We must use an inverted `transform.up` instead of `transform.down` because no `transform.down` exists.